# How to put array's data directly into PriorityQueue

Tags: java, collections, queue

How do you put array's data directly into `PriorityQueue` which implementing `Queue` Interface  ?

```
ContestantFilter [] contestantFilter = new ContestantFilter [50];
contestantFilter [0] = new ContestantFilter("Agnesy Pricillia","IF110026");
contestantFilter [1] = new ContestantFilter("Ellen Shie ","IF110103");
contestantFilter [2] = new ContestantFilter("Wilma Yue Gunawan","EL110021");
.................
.................

Queue<ContestantFilter> queue = new PriorityQueue<ContestantFilter>(1,
                new Comparator<ContestantFilter>() {
                     @Override
                    public int compare(ContestantFilter t1, ContestantFilter t2) {
                        return t1.getID().compareTo(t2.getID());}});
```

I tried

```
for(ContestantFilter c : contestantFilter ){ queue.add(c);}
```

but it's slow .

Something like :

```
queue = ((Queue<ContestantFilter >) Arrays.asList(contestantFilter );
```

Casting doesn't work .

Comment: Why not build a heap from the array like so: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/building-heap-from-array/ then use that heap as a base for your priority queue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`PriorityQueue#addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) method after creating the instance of your queue:

```
//... is a replacement for your custom Comparator<ContestantFilter>
Queue<ContestantFilter> queue = new PriorityQueue(...);
queue.addAll(Arrays.asList(contestantFilter));
```

Comment: This is NOT a `directly` method. It firstly convert an array into a list. Of course, there is not a `directly` method even in Java 11.